# Microsoft Graoph API - Get corresponding Group ID from Team

Tags: microsoft-teams

I get all teams using the following API call:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams
```

How do I get the associated Group ID out of this call?

With the Teams Powershell module it is quite easy:

```
$GroupId = (Get-Team -DisplayName $NewTeamName).GroupId
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot list teams using `/teams`, only get a specific team using `/teams/{group-id}`.

You can however list teams in an org. using this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams)

this returns the `id` amoung others

> Certain unused old teams will not have resourceProvisioningOptions set. For details, see [known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#properties-are-missing-in-the-list-of-teams-that-a-user-has-joined).

---

If you want to get `id`s from the users own joined teams, you can do this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams)

Comment: Many thanks tauzN! When running GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team') it will return ALL Teams regardless the value in resourceProvisioningOptions